# Can't request camera access

Tags: ios, camera, request

I have an app with camera access.
It was working as needed until recent times.
May be it is related to iOS10...

So, here is how I ask user for camera access:

```
- (void)checkCameraAuthorization {
    AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    switch (status) {
        case AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: {
            break;
        }
        case AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
            dispatch_suspend(self.sessionQueue);
            [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
                // never gets here
                dispatch_resume(self.sessionQueue);
            }];
            break;
        }
        default: {
            // denied or restricted;
            isAccessible = NO;
            [self inaccessibleCameraExit];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As I've said this code worked some time ago.

Now, it throws an exception after `AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:` being executed.
If I comment out the call to this method, everything works except camera certainly.

[image]

Exception is not pointing to my code and not in my thread.

So, can you please help me to return camera to working state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `NSCameraUsageDescription` in your info.plist for iOS 10, this is the update from iOS 10.

For more information check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

Comment: Updated my answer added link

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: Glad it helped :)